# c++ OpenCV how can I use EM algorithm on a superpixel?

Tags: c++, opencv, mat, expectation-maximization, superpixels

I need to use the EM algorithm to split out every `superpixel` of my image in two groups using the Expectation Maximization algorithm of OpenCV.

I have initialized the image and the mask of the i-th superpixel, I copied the pixels of my superpixel to a new Mat that is the input of the EM algorithm but I can't understand how can I don't consider the black pixel of the background.

I need to not lose the spatial information of each pixel/superpixel.

[Example of a superpixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcfOP.jpg)

That is my code now

```
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/ximgproc/slic.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ml.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::ml;
using namespace std;


void observe_labels_and_means(const Mat& labels, const Mat& means, int h, int w){

int dimension = 3;

Mat rgb_image(h, w, CV_8UC3);
MatIterator_<Vec3b> rgb_first = rgb_image.begin<Vec3b>();
MatIterator_<Vec3b> rgb_last = rgb_image.end<Vec3b>();
MatConstIterator_<int> label_first = labels.begin<int>();

Mat means_u8;
means.convertTo(means_u8, CV_8UC1, 255.0);
Mat means_u8c3 = means_u8.reshape(dimension);

while(rgb_first != rgb_last){
    const Vec3b& rgb = means_u8c3.ptr<Vec3b>(*label_first)[0];
    *rgb_first = rgb;
    ++rgb_first;
    ++label_first;  
}

imshow("tmp", rgb_image);
waitKey();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

Mat image = imread("Teddy_L.png");
const int image_rows = image.rows;
const int image_cols = image.cols;
int dimension = 3;

//VAR SUPERPIXEL
Mat labels, contour, mask;
int number_sp;
Ptr<cv::ximgproc::SuperpixelSLIC> slic = cv::ximgproc::createSuperpixelSLIC(image);

//SLIC
slic->iterate();
slic->getLabels(labels);
number_sp = slic->getNumberOfSuperpixels();

//TRY ON A SINGLE SUPERPIXEL
mask = (labels==30);
Mat temp(image_rows, image_cols, CV_64FC4);
image.copyTo(temp, mask);
imshow("superpixel", temp);

//INPUT FOR TRAINING
Mat reshaped_temp = temp.reshape(1, image_cols*image_rows);
Mat samples;
reshaped_temp.convertTo(samples, CV_64FC1, 1.0/255.0);
Mat labels_em, probs, log_likelihoods;

//EM
Ptr<EM> em_model = EM::create();
em_model->setClustersNumber(2);
em_model->setCovarianceMatrixType(EM::COV_MAT_DIAGONAL);
    em_model->setTermCriteria(TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT+TermCriteria::EPS,        EM::DEFAULT_MAX_ITERS, 1e-6));

//TRAINING
em_model->trainEM(samples, log_likelihoods, labels, probs);
Mat means = em_model->getMeans();

//RESULT
observe_labels_and_means(labels, means, image_rows, image_cols);

  waitKey();
  return 0;
}
```

I tried with ad image with alpha channel but the background pixel are still considered.

Thanks.